# Can't get Regex to pull mm/dd/yyyy in c#

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I'm working on parsing out a big string, and all is working except grabbing the date.

I've tried putting the following in the Group3 parenthesis in the picture, and then I lose all groups including Group1 and Group2 which were working:

```
^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$

/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/

/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/

^((0|1)\d{1})-((0|1|2)\d{1})-((19|20)\d{2})
```

The best working Regex (gets Group1 and Group2 fine) is:

```
((?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,2})assigned by((?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,2}) on ()
```

And a sample of the data:
"#1 xxxxx xxxxx assigned by Alex xxxxx on 08/10/2018,Request submitted by xxxxx on 08/10/2018,Request created by xxxxx Olander on 08/10/2018
Mailed:  1"

Note: The comma after the date isn't always going to be there.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using ^ and $ anchors? Seems like that’s your problem.

Comment: I got this to work, but I don't understand enough about regex to determine if it is "strong" enough for all my data:  ((?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,2})assigned by((?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,2}) on (\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d)

Comment: What data are you actually trying to extract from the line?

Answer (score 0):

In regex patterns, try not to avoid trying match all that is there by creating sets of things if not needed, but find anchors and use general pattern matching to find what is needed..

The following will use the anchors of `#1`, `submitted by` and `[sp]on[sp]` and then we will do general extractions around that. Finally a basic date pattern will be used to get the date. Note that I am using named group captures to make extraction easier.

```
string data = "#1 xxxxx xxxxx assigned by Alex xxxxx on 08/10/2018,Request submitted by xxxxx on 08/10/2018,Request created by xxxxx Olander on 08/10/2018 Mailed: 1";

string pattern = @"
\#\d+\s+                      # Anchor for the #
(?<Person1>.+?)               # Match Person 1
(?=\sassigned\s)              # Look Ahead for assigned
\sassigned\sby\s              # Consume but don't match assigned
(?<Person2>.+?)               # Match person 2
(?=\son\s)                    # LA for son
\son\s                        # consume
(?<Date>\d\d\D\d\d\D\d\d\d\d) #Get date
";

Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(mt => new {
                         P1 = mt.Groups["Person1"].Value,
                         P2 = mt.Groups["Person2"].Value,
                         DTE = mt.Groups["Date"].Value,
                       } )
```

The result is a list of one item, I surmise you have multiple captures.

[image]